# Unable to install z3

Tags: installation, z3

I'm trying to build Z3 from sources (v. 4.3.1., Nov 2013, z3-89c1785b7322), using make/g++ and Python, with the following results

```
 autoconf                       -- succeeded
 ./configure                    -- succeeded
 python scripts/mk_make.py      -- error message, given below

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "scripts/mk_make.py", line 20, in <module>
mk_makefile()

File "/home/davidg/z3/scripts/mk_util.py", line 854, in mk_makefile
c.mk_makefile(out)

File "/home/davidg/z3/scripts/mk_util.py", line 666, in mk_makefile
for cppfile in self.src_files():

File "/home/davidg/z3/scripts/mk_util.py", line 659, in src_files
return get_cpp_files(self.ex_dir)

File "/home/davidg/z3/scripts/mk_util.py", line 246, in get_cpp_files
return filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.cpp'), os.listdir(path))

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'examples/c++'
```

I don't know if that should be a fatal error.  Proceeding as if it's not,

```
 cd build
 make
```

seem to succeed, concluding with the message "Z3 was successfully built."  The next step

```
 sudo make install
```

fails with the error

```
 No rule to make target `install`
```

(There's also no target for 'uninstall'.)

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Together with the Z3 sources you should have received the examples directory. The configuration fails because it can't find the examples/c++ directory (in which there should be a file called example.cpp). At that point only parts of the Makefile have been written, enough for the main target to succeed, but the install target hasn't been written to the Makefile yet, that's why it fails.